# Compare two folders have same files

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to compare two folders and have them both have the same files. These files have the same name. That is, in folder 'A' it has the files 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', image3.jpg' and folder 'B' has only 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'. I would like both folders to be compared and, in this example, to delete the 'image3.jpg' since it is not in folder 'B'.

I have the following code but it doesn't do anything I want. Can you help me?

```
import filecmp
import os.path

dir1 = "C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive/Escritorio/0"
dir2 = "C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive/Escritorio/1"

def are_dir_trees_equal(dir1, dir2):
    dirs_cmp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    if len(dirs_cmp.left_only)>0 or len(dirs_cmp.right_only)>0 or \
        len(dirs_cmp.funny_files)>0:
        return False
    (_, mismatch, errors) =  filecmp.cmpfiles(
        dir1, dir2, dirs_cmp.common_files, shallow=False)
    if len(mismatch)>0 or len(errors)>0:
        return False
    for common_dir in dirs_cmp.common_dirs:
        new_dir1 = os.path.join(dir1, common_dir)
        new_dir2 = os.path.join(dir2, common_dir)
        if not are_dir_trees_equal(new_dir1, new_dir2):
            return False
    return True
```

I tried with the code that would compare two folders if they both contained the same files, but I couldn't get any result back. I want it to compare both folders and those that do not match are removed from folder 'A' or 'B'.

Comment: Why don't you just copy folder A?

Comment: Maybe writing your own software to do this is the wrong solution for your problem. There are several Windows and Linux tools that do exactly this, such as rsync, robocopy, deltacopy, ...

Comment: Looks tricky, what if the same files have different filenames or the other way around? You might want to use hashing. And indeed there are existing solutions available, also in python, cf https://pypi.org/project/hashdb2/

Answer (score 0):

Simply read file names to list & compare list. #Not tested#Logic you can try

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path   
import os

img_folder_A_list = []
for img in glob.glob("C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive/Escritorio/0/*.jpg"):
    fname= Path(img).name
    img_folder_A_list.append(fname)

img_folder_B_list = []
for img in glob.glob("C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive/Escritorio/1/*.jpg"):
    fname2= Path(img).name
    img_folder_B_list.append(fname2)
    

print(img_folder_A_list) #['image1','image2'....]
print(img_folder_B_list) ##['image1','image2'....]

files_un_matched =  [x for x in img_folder_A_list if x not in img_folder_B_list]

for x in files_un_matched:
    fullpath_duplicate_image =os.path.join('C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive/Escritorio/1', x)
    os.remove(fullpath_duplicate_image)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'm a bit lost in the forum, really, but I don't give up on continuing to learn Python. The code removes the matching ones, but actually I need the opposite, keep the matching ones from both folders and remove the unmatched ones. What should I modify in the code? Thanks.

Comment: My bad sorry...Just edited the code

Comment: No, excuse me. Yesterday I tried 'not' 'not.in' 'in.not' 'not in' 'in not', but I couldn't find the error. I didn't do it right. I am now testing it. Thank you very much

Comment: I have tried the code but I feel that something is wrong. Sometimes it deletes the elements for me and other times it tells me that the element does not exist and gives an error. I will try to explain what the objective would be. Folder A with files, 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg' and Folder B with files, 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg ', 'image6.jpg'. I am looking for the result that both folders, A and B, contain only 'image1.jpg' and 'image2.jpg'. How do I get it?
Thanks.